# Adding more data in array of object in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table of cart with 2 columns (*user_num, data*).

`user_num` will have the phone number of user and
data will have an array of object like `[{ "id": 1, "quantity": 1 }, { "id": 2, "quantity": 2 }, { "id": 3, "quantity": 3 }]` here `id` is product id.

```
 user_num |                                         data
----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1 | [{ "id": 1, "quantity": 1 }, { "id": 2, "quantity": 2 }, { "id": 3, "quantity": 3 }]
```

I want to add more data of products in above array of objects in PostgreSQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Which kind type of column **data**? Is it `JSON` or `JSONB`?

Comment: @Pooya It's JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the value use the JSONB array append operator `||`

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=131198ef35804f9794cf3a395d23a52a)

```sql
update
  test
set
  data = data || '[{"id": 4, "quantity": 4}, {"id": 5, "quantity": 5}]'
where
  user_num = 1;
```

Comment: two more questions, How will I delete an object where id is 4 and How will I edit quantity?

Comment: I hope this sample helps you. I append a sample for updating and deleting property in the array. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=24d8ce885cf0ab1451e1ba4fe96e955a